# Does utmp log contain 'logout' information?

Tags: linux, security, logs, login, wtmp

I have a test yesterday. 
A question is

> Choose the one that is wrong about log files.
>
> 1. utmp **contains** login and **logout information** of the users who are
>      currently logged onto the system
> 2. loginlog records successful login attempts

I know the answer is 2.
But does utmp contain **logout information**? I think 1 is also wrong. wtmp contains logged in and logged out information.
If 1 is also the right answer as I think, What do I support my opinion to instructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[man 5 utmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) gives good answer:

> The **utmp** file allows one to discover information about who is
>   currently using the system.
>
> The **wtmp** file records all logins and logouts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it contains logout information.

When an interactive TUI login session ends, a `DEAD_PROCESS` record is entered into that table, replacing the previous `USER_PROCESS` one.  This record does not live long (on some systems at least), as terminal login service management soon recycles the login service, overwriting the `DEAD_PROCESS` record with a new `GETTY_PROCESS` or `LOGIN_PROCESS` one.  But it can be found there.

On other systems, where there is no such thing as a `GETTY_PROCESS` or `LOGIN_PROCESS` record, it lives for somewhat longer, and is easier to encounter.  However, it is difficult to see outwith programmatically accessing the table, as utilities generally filter `DEAD_PROCESS` entries out when printing the table content.

Furthermore: because of bugs, you will `DEAD_PROCESS` records for GUI login sessions from some modern desktop environments accrue without limit in this table.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- [`pututxline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pututxline.html).   *Base Specifications*.  IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group.